Linear regression model building: Do I need to include variables previously proven significant to a model?
for a school project for an introduction course to linear regression we need to analyze three research questions:

Does fertiliser type affect corn yield? (Yield ~ Fertiliser)
Does corn variety affect corn yield? (Yield ~ Variety)
Do environmental/management factors affect corn yield? (Rainfall, temperature, herbicide use etc.)

When I analyzed the first two research questions (ANOVA + t-tests) I discovered that fertiliser type indeed seems to significantly affect the corn yield and corn variety does not. Now for the third research question I was wondering if I need to include the fertiliser type in the linear model because I already know it's significant or if I can leave it out as I am trying to find the effect of other variables than fertiliser type in this question and collapsibility applies here.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

There are two excellent answers as I write but only one pays passing attention to the fact that this is an assignment. As a university teacher, some of the time, I advise sticking to what you are asked to do unless there is a clear sign that what you are asked to do are merely suggestions and that initiative is encouraged and rewarded,

First, you should not base your decision about including a variable in a multiple regression on whether it was significant in a simple regression or t-test. This is a form of bivariate screening This has been discussed here many times; it is not a good method.
Second, you do not need to include it, but it is probably a good idea. In fact, you should, I think, also include variety, even thought it was not significant. Why?

It could be a valuable control variable and reduce the noise in the model.
The effect of the variables you are most interested in (rainfall, etc) may well be different for different varieties. In fact, just from reading the NY Times and such, I know they are different (maybe not for your particular varieties, but for some. This would require adding interactions and it is rarely a good idea to include interactions without main effects.
Reviewers and readers might laugh at you if you don't include them.

All that said, for your particular third question, you can leave out fertilizer type and variety. You are then looking at the relationship across all types and all varieties. That doesn't strike me as the best method, but it may be what your professor wants.

I guess you mean "reviewers and readers might laugh at you if you don't include variety"? That's currently not so clear. Given that this is an assignment, that "laughing" issue may be irrelevant anyway.

@ChristianHennig Thanks. I clarified that. Regarding the assignment, I guessed that the assignment was trying to mimic some real world example.

As statisticians we'd normally fit a model that includes all potential influences and possibly even interactions (as long as the amount of observations suffices). How the influence of fertiliser and variety plays out can depend on other factors, so for the question whether to include these in an overall model or not, it isn't really relevant whether they are significant on their own, as in principle this can change either way when also considering other factors.
Of course I'm not sure whether this is what you're expected to do, but I'd address all three questions with the same overall model.
(The experimental design may also play a role, but chances are that this wouldn't change anything of what I have written above.)
